# Why is my bootstrap timeline not styling correctly?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

my code isn't working. I'm trying to create a timeline using bootstrap for my work/education. I've used HTML and CSS from a timeline example in W3School but it's not turning out the same when I run it in the browser. When it runs in the browser there is no styling and each paragraph is stacked on top of each other. Can anyone help?

```css
body {
  background-color: #474e5d;
  font-family:"Exo", sans-serif;
}

.timeline {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.timeline::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 6px;
  background-color: white;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -3px;
}

.container left {
  padding: 10px 40px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: inherit;
  width: 50%;
}

.container right {
  padding: 10px 40px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: inherit;
  width: 50%;
}

.container::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  right: -17px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 4px solid #FF9F55;
  top: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
}

.right {
  left: 50%;
}

.left::before {
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 30px;
  border: medium solid white;
  border-width: 10px 0 10px 10px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent white;
}

.right::before {
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 30px;
  border: medium solid white;
  border-width: 10px 10px 10px 0;
  border-color: transparent white transparent transparent;
}

.right::after {
  left: -16px;
}

.content {
  padding: 20px 30px;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.timeline::after {
    left: 31px;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 70px;
    padding-right: 25px;
}

.container::before {
    left: 60px;
    border: medium solid white;
    border-width: 10px 10px 10px 0;
    border-color: transparent white transparent transparent;
}

.left::after, .right::after {
    left: 15px;
}

.right {
    left: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="work/education">
            <section class="work/education">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 my-5">
                    <h2 class="text-uppercase">Work/Education</h2>
            </div>
                <div class="timeline">
                    <div class="container left">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h2>Sep 2014</h2>
                            <p>Enrolled in Business Studies Undergrad at UL</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="container right">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h2>Jan 2017</h2>
                            <p>Began 8-month intership at Liberty Insurance</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="container left">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h2>Aug 2018</h2>
                            <p>Graduated from University</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="container right">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h2>Aug 2018</h2>
                            <p>Began work with Northern Trust Corporation</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="container left">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h2>July 2019</h2>
                            <p>Enrolled in Full-Stack Software Development Course</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="container right">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h2>June 2020</h2>
                            <p>Graduated from Code Institute Course</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Before you copy and paste from w3schools, check the class attribute and how they name the elements. The timeline from w3schools use "container" on the divs for left and right. Bootstrap also use "container" since it's required to use their grid [system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/overview/). Just give "container" for the timeline a different name.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/shanice92/pen/eYNNvqO)

```
<div class="tl_container left">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>Sep 2014</h2>
      <p>Enrolled in Business Studies Undergrad at UL</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Perfect and proper fix. It'd be great if W3schools should disclaim that on https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_timeline.asp.

Comment: Same issue. I couldn't notice it until I found your answer. Thanks a lot!